# ASP.NET MVC Core - View Not Found after publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

After publish, pager buttons from (sakura.AspNetCore) makes wrong URL, missing the site's base folder. For example, in this view: http://localhost/glide/Clientes after clicking the pager button "2", the generated URL is: http://localhost/Clientes?page=2 causing HTTP 404.0 - Not Found because "/glide" is missing.

Startup.cs

app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

ClientesController.cs

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString, string sortOrder, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

        var clientes = from c in _context.ClienteBasico
                       select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            clientes = clientes.Where(c => c.Nome.Contains(searchString));
        }

        var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var pageSize = 5;

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                clientes = clientes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Nome);
                break;
            default:
                clientes = clientes.OrderBy(c => c.Nome);
                break;
        }
        //return View(clientes.ToList());
        return View(clientes.ToPagedList(pageSize, pageNumber));
    }
```

Comment: how do you have your button setup in the view?

Comment: In the View i use: <pager source="@Model" />

Answer (score 1):

You can change how url is generated using `PagerOptions.ItemOptions.Default.Link` property:

```
<pager item-default-link='Sakura.AspNetCore.Mvc.PagerItemLinkGenerators.Format(Url.Content("~") + "/Clientes?page={0:d}")'/>
```